# SFDC, difference between two dates

Tags: salesforce, formula

I'm trying to get the number of days between a start date and end date.

When I do "eDate - sDate" I receeive "Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text."

When I do "DATEVALUE(eDate )-DATEVALUE(sDate)" I receive "Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (Number)."

The date format is "mm/dd/yyyy"
Can someone suggest a fix

Answer (score 0):

Try and use DATETIMEVALUE instead . If its a field change the type accordingly if its a string just add 00:00:00 to end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Field need to be the same Datatype, either Date, or Date/Time, otherwise you'll have to convert them into the same datatype before you evaluate them.